# Curl - response with bad encoding reading a json

Tags: curl, encoding, utf-8, ascii, decode

I'm trying to read a json from nominatim using the Curl command from the command prompt, so I simply typed:

```
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="Tokyo"&format=json"
```

but there's a bad encoding on the japanese characters. This is the response:

```
[{"place_id":258676795,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":1543125,"boundingbox":["20.2145811","35.8984245","135.8536855","154.205541"],"lat":"35.6828387","lon":"139.7594549","display_name":"µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, µùÑµ£¼","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.7593311914925306,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"},{"place_id":20598104,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":2149761647,"boundingbox":["35.6760912","35.6860912","139.7621861","139.7721861"],"lat":"35.6810912","lon":"139.7671861","display_name":"µ¥▒Σ║¼, Keiyo Street, Σ╕╕πü«σåà1, Σ╕╕πü«σåà, σìâΣ╗úτö░σî║, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, 100-0005, µùÑµ£¼","class":"railway","type":"station","importance":0.5591218901586479,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//transport_train_station2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":70003988,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":6396868334,"boundingbox":["35.6727691","35.6827691","139.7596365","139.7696365"],"lat":"35.6777691","lon":"139.7646365","display_name":"µ¥▒Σ║¼, Θì¢σå╢µ⌐ïΘÇÜπéè, Σ╕╕πü«σåà2, Σ╕╕πü«σåà, σìâΣ╗úτö░σî║, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, 100-0005, µùÑµ£¼","class":"railway","type":"station","importance":0.5591218901586479,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//transport_train_station2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":71190469,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":6397207541,"boundingbox":["35.6771116","35.6871116","139.7606744","139.7706744"],"lat":"35.6821116","lon":"139.7656744","display_name":"µ¥▒Σ║¼, Σ╕╕πü«σåà1, Σ╕╕πü«σåà, σìâΣ╗úτö░σî║, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, 100-0005, µùÑµ£¼","class":"railway","type":"station","importance":0.5591218901586479,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//transport_train_station2.p.20.png"},{"place_id":259023488,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":5303898,"boundingbox":["35.632591","35.688161","139.517033","139.593089"],"lat":"35.660036","lon":"139.554815","display_name":"Φ¬┐σ╕âσ╕é, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, µùÑµ£¼","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.5022260781248801,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"},{"place_id":259078458,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":5301789,"boundingbox":["35.604698","35.657961","139.393498","139.4739366"],"lat":"35.637188","lon":"139.443503","display_name":"σñÜµæ⌐σ╕é, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, µùÑµ£¼","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.4888462520106494,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"},{"place_id":258856136,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"relation","osm_id":1759475,"boundingbox":["35.618431","35.650744","139.561968","139.594114"],"lat":"35.634023","lon":"139.575977","display_name":"τï¢µ▒ƒσ╕é, µ¥▒Σ║¼Θâ╜, µùÑµ£¼","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.470967951474371,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"},{"place_id":46725894,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"node","osm_id":3728940234,"boundingbox":["-5.8168777","-5.7768777","142.8181612","142.8581612"],"lat":"-5.7968777","lon":"142.8381612","display_name":"Tokyo, Hayapuga Rural LLG, Tari-Pori District, Hela, Highlands Region, Papua Niugini","class":"place","type":"hamlet","importance":0.36,"icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_place_village.p.20.png"},{"place_id":94556779,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":23921332,"boundingbox":["14.6744911","14.6761699","121.0951871","121.097869"],"lat":"14.6754461","lon":"121.0967373","display_name":"Tokyo, Batasan Hills, 2nd District, Quezon City, Eastern Manila District, Metro Manila, 2, Mindanao","class":"highway","type":"residential","importance":0.21},{"place_id":146821334,"licence":"Data ┬⌐ OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":226371613,"boundingbox":["7.0842449","7.0880334","125.5133359","125.5133699"],"lat":"7.0861394","lon":"125.5133561","display_name":"Tokyo, Samulco Village, Cawa-Cawa, Santo Ni├▒o, Davao City, Davao Region, 8022, Mindanao","class":"highway","type":"residential","importance":0.21}]
```

so I'd like to know if there's a way to visualize these characters correctly (probably including the right parameters in the curl string.)
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from a linux-command-line?

In Linux **without a GUI/X-Windows** I cannot see Chinese char. in vi or vim or on the command level. If I redirect the curl output to a file, and open it with a browser, then I see the characters.
You can set charset with curl, but that will not solve this issue in this situation.
Example:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" ...`

In Linux **with a GUI/ X-Windows**, I can see the Chinese chars in vi etc.

In both cases the charset is UTF-8 and can display Chinese characters.

Comment: No, I'm working on Windows. I know, running the code on https://reqbin.com/curl I correctly see the result, the problem is the response from the console of the windows command prompt so I suppose that there's a different encoding by Windows but I don't know if it is possible to change the charset of the json response before "printing" the result on the console...

Comment: In the windows shell activate a code page for chinese characters: chcp 936.
Then run your curl command. You will see the chinese characters in the shell.